# Error While Trying to build LLVM in Debug+Asserts mode

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I am trying to learn how to build an LLVM pass. The LLVM documentation at 
http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#writing-an-llvm-pass-functionpass

states that LLVM needs to be built in Debug+Asserts mode from the build directory. However, when I build it, I get the following error after this line on the terminal "Linking Debug+Asserts executable clang-tidy". The compilation exits after this step.

I am doing all this on a Debian 7 XFCE distro which is running on a VMware virtual machine with 3 gigs of memory(it was increased from 2 gigs).

I first thought that this might be due to low memory with the VM, however I increased it from 2 GB to 3 GB.

However I am still getting the error and the compilation still exits.

Can anyone tell me how to go about this and what might be causing the error.

Comment: To be sure that you really have a memory issue, look at the output of dmesg immediately after the compilation stop, it should mention the oom killer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3Gb may still be too small amount to link llvm and clang in Debug mode. I would suggest to increase the memory limit to 6-8 Gb. You may also try to use gold as a linker.